# dlookup to get values from two tables

Tags: ms-access

I need `dlookup` to get the most recent time from two tables

```
=DLookUp("[TimeStamp]","tbl_TimeStamps_Daily","[TimeStamp] = DMax(""[TimeStamp]"",""tbl_TimeStamps_Daily &

("[TimeStamp]","tbl_TimeStamps_Monthend","[TimeStamp] = DMax(""[TimeStamp]"",""tbl_TimeStamps_Daily"",)")))
```

Comment: Well, can't do that. Need two DLookup calcs.

Comment: Actually, you already have the most recent TimeStamp from tbl_TimeStamps_Daily with DMax(). Why don't you just use DMax() on tbl_TimeStamps_Monthend? What are you really trying to accomplish? Show sample data and desired output as formatted text tables.

Comment: Consider using a UNION query  (`SELECT TOP 1 TimeStamp FROM tbl_TimeStamps_Daily ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC UNION ....`) as the basis for a quick recordset.

Comment: Thanks much - The UNION Query was the way to go. The UNION query was used as the record source for what I already have set up with DMax().. Grateful....